# PDF Viewer for Ionic 2: cannot import or require

Tags: javascript, pdf, angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

I am trying to build a PDF viewing component for an Ionic 2 app. I have lots of experience of Angular 2, but not of Ionic.

The component will be built using [pdf.js](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js) and have created the pdf.js asset to be included in my project as described on the github page. However, trying to `require` this fails  — `require is not defined` —, so I copied the script to the asset folder and tried importing it. It seems the file is not being copied to the build so that fails too.

Anyone have any pointers for requiring or importing a non-weboack non-SystemJS script into an Ionic 2 app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a `js` folder (or something like this) in the `www` folder; include the files needed and reference them from there.  This folder is not emptied on build.

**EDIT**

The root of the `www` folder does not change and you can reference it as someting like ... `'js/need-this.js'`.

There should have some references in your `index.html` file to the `build` folder and maybe the `assets` folder (icon); this concept of using a `js` folder works the same. Only `build` and `assets` will change.

Comment: But does the folder structure not change when comparing build time and run time? How do I require/import the file in my component?

Comment: The structure does change ... however, the root of the `www` folder does not change and you can reference it. `'js/need-this.js'`.  You should have some reference in your index.html file to build and maybe assets; works the same only build and assets can change.

Comment: Nice on mate, got it working now. I was confusing build time 'imports' with runtime hrefs! Ionic is a little quirky for me, a slight departure from Angular 2. Inculcating the documentation at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

I feel that I should point out that you shouldn't copy anything into `www` since this is autogenerated and any changes will be overwritten. You should copy into `assets` instead.